# In EIGEN c++ cannot multiply vector by it's transpose

Tags: c++, eigen, transpose

While executing the below code I'm getting this error: "INVALID_VECTOR_VECTOR_PRODUCT__IF_YOU_WANTED_A_DOT_OR_COEFF_WISE_PRODUCT_YOU_MUST_USE_THE_EXPLICIT_FUNCTIONS"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense> 
using namespace Eigen;
int main()
{
    Vector3d v(1, 2, 3);
    Vector3d vT = v.transpose();
    Matrix3d ans = v*vT;
    std::cout << ans << std::endl;
}
```

Is there any other way of doing this without the compiler complaining ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Vector3d` is defined as a column vector, hence both `v` and `vT` are column vectors. Therefore, the operation `v*vT` doesn't make sense. What you want to do is

```
Matrix3d ans = v*v.transpose();
```

or define `vT` as a `RowVector3d`

```
Vector3d v(1, 2, 3);
RowVector3d vT = v.transpose();
Matrix3d ans = v*vT;
```